# How to make mysql-slow.log not telling me that I am not using index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-slow-query-log

The table named `markets` having such columns: `id`, `visible`, `position`, and I created index on visible, every time

and the slow-log always

```
# Time: 2021-05-12T00:46:14.248654Z
# User@Host: tase[tase] @ ip-172-31-22-13.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal [172.31.22.13]  Id: 134987
# Query_time: 0.000155  Lock_time: 0.000048 Rows_sent: 7  Rows_examined: 17
SET timestamp=1620780374;
SELECT `markets`.* FROM `markets` WHERE `markets`.`visible` = TRUE ORDER BY `markets`.`position` DESC;
```

and the Explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys           | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | markets | NULL       | ALL  | index_markets_on_visible| NULL | NULL    | NULL |   10 |    70.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+

1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I am wondering:

1. I have created the index:  `index_markets_on_visible`, why still the query was logged and considered as: "not indexed query"
2. How to solve this issue? should I add index to the "order by" column?

thanks.

Comment: An index on a boolean column is a complete waste of time and space. It just partions the column into TRUE and FALSE, i.e. on average into half the number of rows. So it isn't going to materially improve performance. So MySQL ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_queries_not_using_indexes';
```

It will probably say `ON`.  Turn it `OFF`.  (And you have found why I think that setting is mostly useless.)

If you want to have a useful index, make the composite index `INDEX(visible, position)`.

It may still say that it is not using any index.  Here's the reason for that.  7/17 of the rows match `visible = TRUE`.  That is more than (about) 20% of the table, so the Optimizer decides that it is not worth using the index, but it may be faster to simply scan all 17 rows, skipping the non-`visible` ones.

Another note:  If it does use my index, it will avoid the "using filesort", which gives another boost in performance.